# Random set of columns from a database

Tags: android, database

So far i have managed to display the contents of a row(4 columns) in specific textviews. But i want to display them in random.
I use this

```
String answer1 = cur.getString(cur.getColumnIndex("ANSWER1"));
```

and on click the content change but always the data on column ANSWER1 shows in the first textview. What can i do to random display the 4 columns to the 4 textviews? E.g column 1 to textview 3, column 2 to textview 1 etc.I want everytime different data on textview 1.
----Edit----
Lets say i have one more column that idicates the number of the column the correct answer is.E.g if the correct answer is in the column "Answer3" the data in the column "CorrAnswer" is 3. I change the textviews above to buttons. Each button sends an integer. How can i check the correct answer when the texts on the buttons are shuffled?

Comment: the fact you want to get random columns strongly suggests your schema is not normalised.  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization

Comment: Let me be more specific. I want to dispay data from each column in not a predifined order in the textviews. Nothing to do with normalization.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would add all of your answers to an ArrayList, and then use a Random to remove random answers. The following Java (console) code shows how you might do this:

```
    ArrayList<String> lstAnswers = new ArrayList<String>();
    lstAnswers.add("Answer 1");
    lstAnswers.add("Answer 2");
    lstAnswers.add("Answer 3");
    lstAnswers.add("Answer 4");

    Random random = new Random();


    while (lstAnswers.size() > 0) {
        int index = random.nextInt(lstAnswers.size());
        String randomAnswer = lstAnswers.remove(index);
        System.out.println(randomAnswer);
    }
```

As requested in your edit, the following would assign the text to the text views:

```
    ArrayList<String> lstAnswers = new ArrayList<String>();
    lstAnswers.add("Answer 1");
    lstAnswers.add("Answer 2");
    lstAnswers.add("Answer 3");
    lstAnswers.add("Answer 4");

    Random random = new Random();

    int[] textViews = new int[] { R.id.txt1, R.id.txt2, R.id.txt3, R.id.txt4 };
    int textViewIndex = 0;

    while (lstAnswers.size() > 0) {
        int index = random.nextInt(lstAnswers.size());
        String randomAnswer = lstAnswers.remove(index);

        ((TextView)findViewByid(textViews[textViewIndex])).setText(randomAnswer);

        ++textViewIndex;
    }
```

Comment: I do not want to remove the answers but your answer could work. If i want to the sting in a specific index of the arraylist and show it to a textview how i could do that?

Comment: The remove only removes the string from the temporary arraylist: they won't be removed from the database

Comment: To add the string to a text view, inside the while loop call textView.set text(random answer). However, if it needs to be a different textview every iteration then you will need to maintain a reference to which textviews have not yet been set.